# I need a way to calculate volume from picture taked from Smart phone camera

Tags: image-processing, augmented-reality, arcore, smartphone, depth

We plan to make an application that can calculate calories by taking a picture of the food item. In the first stage, we will use image processing to extract the type of food, for example, to say that this food is a piece of chocolate cake, but we want to extract the size information from the image as well. We want to know the distance between the camera and the food item so that we can calculate the area of ​​the food. We will ask the user to take a picture from the top and side picture to calculate the top area and height of the cake.
Are there any useful ways to extract this information? We were planning to use ARCore to take the information from the depth camera in the smartphone, as most new phones have this feature. Still, we want sources to implement the idea practically, or are there other ways to do it? For extracting dimension information using augmented reality, we need a way to get the width and height of the cake to calculate the volume.

Comment: You will need *stereoscopic reconstruction*, but also *image segmentation*, to isolate the different ingredients.

Comment: "calories from picture"? I think I saw that question asked before...